# Credit Card Validation - match pattern with white spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, credit-card, typescript

I am building a credit card form where I want to validate card with checkValidity by matching its respective card pattern which I dynamically add to input.

Suppose the user enters a mastercard, say - `5454545454545454` , which after formatting and adding spaces looks like `5454 5454 5454 5454` . Then I dynamically change pattern attribute for that field to mastercard's regex - `^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$`, where on input blur I trigger checkValidity, which returns false when it should not.

I guess this is due to the formatting I did, as it adds spaces to value and the pattern fails.

So my problem is that I am not able to get a solution to validate pattern with spaces for that given regex or how could I remove spaces when validating the pattern with checkValidity or how should I add space to that given regex or what other solution is there for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this one easily. I understand you load CC number dynamically or get CC number from user input and then you validate it somewhere after its entered with spaces added.

You can use `.replace()` JS function to remove any white spaces in the CC number and send that number for validation which will work just fine.

You can read more about .replace() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for details.

I have created a quick example for you below. Run snippet to see it working.

```js
//Dynamicall add number for example only
var ccNumber = '1234567890123456';
var addSpaces = ccNumber.match(/.{1,4}/g);
$('#credit-card').val(addSpaces.join(' '));

//Getting card number and removing white spaces
var getCardNumber = $('#credit-card').val()
var NoSpacesCCNumber = getCardNumber.replace(/\s+/g, '')
console.log('No spaces for validation = ' + NoSpacesCCNumber)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label" for="credit-card">Credit card</label>
<input id="credit-card" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text" />
```

Comment: what i am looking to is when doing checkValidity i want a regex pattern that will ignore white spaces and allow it to match else what to do something before checkValidity to set the value for input to be without spaces

Comment: @TapanDave can you please update the question by adding some reproducible code including your function checkValidity as well. Please add all the relevant code so I can help further it be easy then. Thanks.